# can warn.filterwarnings be set to act locally when testing with nosetests

Tags: python, nose, skbio

I'm running into some trouble with filtering warnings in python tests when using `nosetests`. I'd like my call to `warn.filterwarnings` to be local only to a single file, but instead if any of the files I test with `nosetests` calls `warn.filterwarnings`, warnings are filtered in all of the tests. For example (from the [scikit-bio code base](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio)), `skbio/math/diversity/beta/tests/test_base.py` does not have a call to `warn.filterwarnings`, so as expected if a warning is generated during the tests, it is printed to the screen:

```
$ nosetests skbio/math/diversity/beta/tests/test_base.py
../Users/caporaso/Dropbox/code/skbio/skbio/math/diversity/beta/base.py:89: UserWarning: pw_distances_from_table is deprecated. In the future (tentatively scikit-bio 0.2.0), pw_distance will take a biom.table.Table object and this function will be removed. You will need to update your code to call pw_distances at that time.
  warn("pw_distances_from_table is deprecated. In the future (tentatively "
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.017s

OK
```

However, in `skbio/core/alignment/tests/test_pairwise.py`, there is a call to `warn.filterwarnings`. If I run those tests before `skbio/math/diversity/beta/tests/test_base.py`, the above warning is not printed:

```
$ nosetests skbio/core/alignment/tests/test_pairwise.py skbio/math/diversity/beta/tests/test_base.py
...................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 19 tests in 0.056s

OK
```

I'd like to have the warning from `skbio/math/diversity/beta/tests/test_base.py` printed, even if other `warn.filterwarnings` is called from other test files. In practice, I'll end up filtering that as well, but I want to know if there are other warnings not being caught by the tests elsewhere in my test suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you want to use conext managers to [temporarily suppress them](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Specifically what I did was remove all calls to ``warn.filterwarnings`` from my test suite, and then wrap the calls that were raising warnings as suggested in the link you sent.